# Lettrine and Wrapfig

Tags: wrapfigure, lettrine

How can I use lettrine at the start of a paragraph used in the wrapfigure environment.

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newcounter{cnt}\setcounter{cnt}{0}
\def\t{\stepcounter{cnt}\thecnt. cat sat on the mat. }



\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
        \vspace{1ex}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1in]{image}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lettrine{T}{he cat sat} \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
\end{document}
```

Which yields the following result, I have shifted the image down so that the problem is made more apparent, ie, wrapfig is ignored.

[image]

**NOTE:** David Carlisle has provided a pretty good answer so far, however, the following anomalies occur with the output, specifically, an update was made to David's original code to allow the modified lettrine (`wflettrine{...}`) to take the optional arguments in order to control the letter height etc, however, by default, the following output is returned if the optional argument `lines=5` is now parsed.

[image: wflettrine5]

The above was achieved with the code command:

```
\wflettrine[lines=5]{T}{he cat sat}
```

And it is clear to see under the red-highlighted region, that the drop-cap letter is not taking up the whole space, strangely enough, the same behavior was observed on my machine with the default computer-modern font, under a normal use of lettrine.

By changing the font to Helvetica, via the use of the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

And executing the same command, yields the following output.

[image: wflettrine_helvet]

And it is clear that the previous problem is resolved (by the correct drop-cap usage under the green highlighted section), however, this has pushed the wrapfig component to the right, as can be seen under the red-highlighted section.

It appears as though the wrapfig has been pushed to the right by what appears to be the same amount as the width of the dropcap letter 'T'.

Comment: Both `\lettrine` and `wrapfig` try setting a `\parshape`. The specification made by `\lettrine` comes second, so it wins.

Comment: Scissor paper rock.

Comment: Probably `\lettrine` should examine the current `\parshape` and modify it, rather than specifying a new one. As things stand it doesn't seem straightforward to modify how `\lettrine` works.

Comment: The small T is nothing to do with this code, just that lettrine presumably uses `\fontsize{x}{y}\selectfont` and by default the cm fonts are restricted to sizes available in the original bitmap scales. add `\usepackage{fix-cm}` and cm will be scalable like helvetica. I don't see the images being pushed out, see the image in my answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{helvet}\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newcounter{cnt}\setcounter{cnt}{0}
\def\t{\stepcounter{cnt}\thecnt. cat sat on the mat. }


\newdimen\tttaa
\newdimen\tttbb

\renewcommand\thepage{\the\numexpr(\value{page}+1)/2\relax}

\makeatletter
\def\merge@ps{\afterassignment\merge@ps@\tttbb}

\def\merge@ps@{\afterassignment\merge@ps@@\tttaa}


\def\merge@ps@@{%
\afterassignment\reset@WF@ps\dimen@\WF@ps\valign
%\showthe\count@
\ifnum\count@>\@ne
\advance\count@\m@ne
\expandafter\merge@ps
\fi
}


\def\reset@WF@ps{\afterassignment\reset@WF@ps@\dimen@ii}

\def\reset@WF@ps@#1\valign{%
\edef\new@wf@ps{\new@wf@ps
  \the\dimexpr\dimen@+\tttbb\relax\space
  \the\dimexpr\dimen@ii-\tttbb\relax\space}%
 \def\WF@ps{#1}}


\newcommand\wflettrine[3][]{%
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{\lettrine[#1]{#2}{#3}\global\let\gtmp\L@parshape}%
  \afterassignment\wf@getoffset\count@\gtmp\hoffset
  \setbox\WF@box\hbox{\kern-\dimen@\box\WF@box\kern\dimen@}%
  \noindent\box\tw@
    \def\new@wf@ps{}%
    \afterassignment\merge@ps\count@\gtmp
    \edef\WF@ps{\new@wf@ps\space\WF@ps}%
    \@@parshape\c@WF@wrappedlines\WF@ps\z@\columnwidth}


\def\wf@getoffset{\afterassignment\wf@get@ffset\dimen@}
\def\wf@get@ffset#1\hoffset{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
        \vspace{1ex}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1in]{image}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \wflettrine[lines=5]{T}{he cat sat}
    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
        \vspace{1ex}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1in]{image}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \wflettrine{T}{he cat sat}
    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \lettrine[lines=5]{T}{he cat sat}
    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
        \vspace{1ex}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1in]{image}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    The cat sat
    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David, this is exactly what I want, however, the `wflettrine` command doesn't take the optional arguments ie `\wflettrine[lines=4]{W}{ord}`. Passing the extra argument on isn't difficult, the lines get changed, but the dropcap letter doesn't, so which part of your above code controls the actual dropcap letter?

Comment: @ADP I didn't know it had an optional arg:-) fixed.

Comment: What you have done (the new edit), is what I did, however, you will notice that whilst the number of lines increases, the size of the drop-cap letter does not. If you use the command `\wflettrine[lines=5]{T}{he cat sat}` you will see what I mean. Strange thing is, the same behaviour occurs under normal wrapfig using computermodern font, so, try with helvetica font (ie put in pramble `\usepackage{helvet}\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`), the letter size changes correctly, but, the wrapfig spacing is put out...

Comment: Please see my updated question, which should clarify better.

Comment: @ADP OK I see, that'll be fixable. Will look later.

Comment: @ADP try now...

Comment: Many thanks, I appreciate your effort. Not sure if you are able to annotate your code, so I (and others) can understand what you have done, but nonetheless, you deserve the credit for this solution. Cheers.

Comment: I have a problem when using as the lettrine it's too lowered. This can be corrected with the argument loversize as in \lettrine[loversize=0.1]{T}{O} however that 'loversize' argument can't be passed to wflettrine

Comment: @Álvaro The version after the the jul 1 edit should allow the optional argument?