# wrapfig doesn't detect paragraph

Tags: wrapfigure, acro

Working with wrapfig I have encountered some strange behavior involving the use of commands (of acro package) to start a paragraph (Similar to this: [lettrine and wrapfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119688/lettrine-and-wrapfig)). Wrapfig does not detect the start of the paragraph and even worse, it does not end.

Is there any way around this? Thanks.

A MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareAcronym{bosscha}{   short =     {Bosscha},   long =      {Johannes Bosscha Jr\acdot}, }

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering 
    \rule{3cm}{7cm}
    \caption{V.S.M. van der Willigen}
\end{wrapfigure}

\ac{bosscha}, 17 years of age, \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

### EDIT:

Using the solution in the answer with InsertBoxR I have encountered some problems with the layout.

Script:
`\InsertBoxR{0}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{./Figures/06vdWilligen}
    \captionof{figure}{\acl{willigen}}
  \end{minipage}}[2]`
Result:
[image: with InsertBoxR. Undesirable is the line break and the caption seems to go over unwrapped text.]

Wrapfig looks like this (if we workaround the list/acro problem.[image: with Wrapfig. Nice space above picture for aesthetics, no wrapping problems]

PS: I have encountered similar problems with wrapfig and the color package.

Comment: wrapfig does not support following list environments, possibly `\ac` is some kind of a list-like environment. I used the following (ugly) workaround just for debugging (it works): `\newcommand{\longForm}{Johannes Bosscha Jr}
\newcommand{\shortForm}{Bosscha}
\DeclareAcronym{bosscha}{short = {\shortForm}, long = {\longForm\acdot},}` and instead of `\ac{bosscha} ...` I used: `\longForm{} (\shortForm), 17 years of age, \lipsum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\ac` at the start of a paragraph begins the paragraph inside a local group, which confuses wrapfig. Start the paragraph like Anton says, or `\mbox{}\ac{bosscha}` or `leavevmode\ac{bosscha}` or `\indent\ac{bosscha}`. The placement and wrapping will be correct.

Note that `\ac` does `\leavevmode` internally, but not at the beginning where it makes sense, but inside grouping.

Comment: All these solutions seem to work. Thanks for (I think) correctly addressing the underlying problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can have an easy solution with the `insbox` *plain TeX* macro package: use the `\InsertBoxR{no of unshortened lines}{inserted object}[corrective number]`.

The optional corrective number is the number of additional shorter lines, in case TeX doesn't compute the correct number.

You can't use  a floating environment in the second argument of this macro, so  simply insert your graphic, and use the `\captionof` command from `caption`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\input{insbox}
\DeclareAcronym{bosscha}{ short = {Bosscha}, long = {Johannes Bosscha Jr\acdot}, }

\makeatletter
\@InsertBoxMargin=8pt %% default is 2 mm
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\InsertBoxR{0}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \captionsetup{format=hang, justification=raggedright, font=small}
    \centering \rule{3cm}{7cm}
    \captionof{figure}{V.S.M. van der Willigen}
  \end{minipage}}[2]

\ac{bosscha}, 17 years of age, \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, although it is difficult to obtain the same layout as wrapfig (the rest of my document depends on it..)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain  the difference with what `wrapfig` should yield?

Answer (score 2):

Try to write  `\mbox{\ac{bosscha}}` instead of `\ac{bosscha}`.