# Lettrine and Wrapfig in an xcookybooky recipe

Tags: paragraphs, lettrine, wrapfig, parshape, xcookybooky

I have a problem regarding the combination of `lettrine` and `wrapfig` inside an `xcookybooky` recipe.

My issue stems from the interaction between the two packages. If I create a recipe such as that shown below, the paragraph maintains that width even when the ingredients wraptable has finished. This creates unsightly white-space in the document.

[image: Example Recipe with no wrapping]

To fix this, I stumbled across a solution by David Carlisle which uses some fancy LaTeX to combine the two paragraph shapes (see [Lettrine and Wrapfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119688/lettrine-and-wrapfig)).
This works well, however there is still an issue. Whenever the end of the ingredients list coincides with the start of a new preparation step, an error is thrown.

[image: Error from wflettrine code]

This can be replicated in the following MWE by reducing the length of the ingredients list (i.e. the height of the `wrapfig`). I have managed to reduce the number of lines affected by 1 with the shift the `valign` command inside the conditional, however the issue still remains for the first two lines of each paragraph.

To get to my question, is there a way to fix the `\wflettrine` command to make this work? Or is there another approach which will solve the root issue?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcookybooky}

%------------------------------------------------
%   Modification of lettrine for wrapfig
%------------------------------------------------
% Courtesy of David Carlisle: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119688/lettrine-and-wrapfig

\newdimen\tttaa
\newdimen\tttbb

\makeatletter
\def\merge@ps{\afterassignment\merge@ps@\tttbb}
\def\merge@ps@{\afterassignment\merge@ps@@\tttaa}
\def\merge@ps@@{%
    % \afterassignment\reset@WF@ps\dimen@\WF@ps\valign
    \ifnum\count@>\@ne
        \afterassignment\reset@WF@ps\dimen@\WF@ps\valign  % <-- moving to here increases the lines available by one
        \advance\count@\m@ne
        \expandafter\merge@ps
    \fi%
}

\def\reset@WF@ps{\afterassignment\reset@WF@ps@\dimen@ii}
\def\reset@WF@ps@#1\valign{%
    \edef\new@wf@ps{
        \new@wf@ps
        \the\dimexpr\dimen@+\tttbb\relax\space
        \the\dimexpr\dimen@ii-\tttbb\relax\space%
    }%
    \def\WF@ps{#1}%
}%

\newcommand\wflettrine[3][]{%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{\lettrine[#1]{#2}{#3}\global\let\gtmp\L@parshape}%
    \afterassignment\wf@getoffset\count@\gtmp\hoffset
    \setbox\WF@box\hbox{\kern-\dimen@\box\WF@box\kern\dimen@}%
    \noindent\copy\tw@
    \def\new@wf@ps{}%
    \afterassignment\merge@ps\count@\gtmp
    \edef\WF@ps{\new@wf@ps\space\WF@ps}%
    \@@parshape\c@WF@wrappedlines\WF@ps\z@\columnwidth%
}

\def\wf@getoffset{\wf@get@ffset\dimen@}
\def\wf@get@ffset#1\hoffset{}

\makeatother

%------------------------------------------------
%   Update of xcookybook for wrapping steps
%------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\step}{%
    \par
    \stepcounter{step}  % <-- moved here, since shouldn't be in the argument of lettrine
    \wflettrine[%
        lines=2,
        lhang=0,          % space into margin, value between 0 and 1
        loversize=0.15,   % enlarges the height of the capital
        slope=0em,
        findent=1em,      % gap between capital and intended text
        nindent=0em       % shifts all intended lines, beginning with the second line
    ]{\thestep}{}%
}
\newcommand{\ing}{1 tsp & some ingredient}

%------------------------------------------------
%   Document
%------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{recipe}{Example Recipe}

    \ingredients[5]{%%%% <-- CHANGE TO 4 TO SEE ERROR  %%%%
        \ing\\\ing\\\ing\\\ing
    }

    \preparation{%
        \step xxx
        \step yyy
        \step \lipsum[1]
        \step \lipsum[1]
        \step \lipsum[1]
    }

\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example Recipe with wrapping, but missing \valign error]

Comment: are you sure about `% <-- moving to here increases the lines available by one` ....

Comment: Doing this decreased the minimum number of lines a step is required to be before the end of a wrapfig, going from three to two. Effectively increasing the number of lines available by one. It seemed to hold up under any of the tests I threw at it. However, I'll defer to your judgement if you think that this will end up causing other issues?

Comment: don't ask me, I have no idea how this works:-)