# Image Not Wrapping Correctly

Tags: wrapfigure, text

Question is as stated. I'm trying to get my text to wrap around my image, yet no matter what I do it seems to do create this big white space in addition to an L0.3 text that pops up. Any idea how I'd troubleshoot this?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows other to reproduce the issue you describe and add this code directly into your question.

Comment: What error is overflow telling you?  I don't suppose you've forgotten to load the package?

Comment: don't show code as a screenhoot add an example on site as text also show teh full error message from the log. Combining lettrine and wrapfig is tricky though, if you really have to do that then see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119688/lettrine-and-wrapfig/121555#121555

Comment: I forgot to load the package, oh what a great day. Solved the problem, thank you so much.

Comment: Wonderful divination @Teepeemm! That picture looks big enough that it could be presented better in a regular figure with a caption on the side.