How to use drop caps with wrapped text
I'm trying to wrap paragraph text around a framed text box, while using drop caps. I'm not set on using any particular package. My current approach using lettrine and wrapfig gets close, but the two do not play well together.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{3cm}
\begin{framed}
\scriptsize In sit maiores fugit quis facilis eum blanditiis.
\end{framed}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lettrine{I}{n} sit maiores fugit quis facilis eum blanditiis illo. Nam 
labore est temporibus omnis officia quae qui. Quibusdam laboriosam 
similique est perferendis corrupti. Dolor sed fugiat a illum aspernatur 
cumque dignissimos temporibus. Nulla similique corporis qui. Perspiciatis 
nisi recusandae molestiae consequatur odio fugit magnam neque.

\end{document}


Removing \lettrine gives the correct result, but obviously no drop cap,

This question gives some insight into the source of the problem, but the solution is a bit beyond me.
Is there a simple solution?

sorry I closed as duplicate but I see you mentioned the duplicate in the question so I re-opened. I'm not sure what else to say though, this question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121555/1090, lettrine and wrapfig are both relatively complicated packages so code to combine them is a bit compliciated but like the package code you don't need to understand the code, you just stick it in your preamble and then it should work, If it does not work, make an example and ask about that.

you could try with one of the other wrapping packages if those work any better e.g. wrapfig2 or wrapstuff. note that I have no idea whether they do. probably @DavidCarlisle would have suggested them already if they did.

@cfr Thank you for the suggestions. wrapstuff is close to working, but the drop cap is forced into the margin.

@DavidCarlisle I was able to get your solution working I think, so thank you. I wish it wasn't necessary though.

wellsuch a thing os always necessary, it does not have to be in your document preamble, stick it in a wrlettrine,sty and use \usepackage{wrlettrine} then the code is no more or less necassary than the code in any other package.

As I re-opened it I can not close but this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121555/1090 if anyone with a close vote wants to close.
